# How to record this kind of video stream?

Tags: windows, video-streaming, video-capture

I don't know what this kind of streaming is called, its not classic protocols I've encountered.

I want to record few shows (debates) on Govt news channel: http://webcast.gov.in. Its a free news channel.

All I could figure out is that they are using Strobe Media Player and it is using this mansifest.f4m:

```
http://164.100.31.234/hds-live/livepkgr/_definst_/ddnewslive.f4m
```

its an XML file, I'm unable to record the stream. I tried feeding this URL to VLC media player and KMPlayer hoping to record using it. Then I also tried it downloading using DownloadHelper firefox addon. But no luck.

I don't know much about the media streaming but they seem to use "Adobe Flash Media Server":

```
http://164.100.31.234/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *.f4m* extention indicates usage of the Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS) technology. With HDS, the original MP4 or FLV file is split up into many F4F segments, which are then served to the media player on the page one after the other, so there is no single video file to download like with most other video streaming technologies.

It is easy to download the individual F4F segments, but then they need to be recombined into the original video file. There is a script for this, called [AdobeHDS.php](https://github.com/K-S-V/Scripts/wiki).

There is a step-by-step usage guide found here:
https://n1njahacks.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/how-to-save-hds-flash-streams-from-any-web-page/

Answer (score 2):

If realplayer doesn't capture it:

[Realplayer One Click Video Downloader](http://www.real.com/in/features/basic/download)

You can always film your screen using software like fraps and bandicam (both .com for their respective sites. I can't make more URLs as my reputation is too low).

And if necessary, edit the video by cutting out the essential. I found this actually to be the easiest method if you count the hours searching how to capture *that* specific videostream, and it works for everything obviously.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/342430-F4F-capturing-converting) should be helpful. Describes full solution.

Video You want to download is Adobe HDS(HTTP Dynamic Streaming).
 It provides(Adobe HDS) packetized stream of different qualities and it can be encrypted(DRM).

Provided link explains how to use browser, local PHP installation and PHP script to
save and join the streamed parts.

In the post [#51](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/342430-F4F-capturing-converting?p=2199352&viewfull=1#post2199352) there is standalone solution posted with usage instructions; unzip and run.

Comment: You should summarize the salient points, suggestions, and accepted solution from that thread, here in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There exist many Flash downloaders, but as most of them are implemented as browser extensions,
the one you should get depends on the browser that you are using.

A very good downloader is [RealPlayer](http://real.com/), which adapts itself to most major browsers.

For Firefox, a good extension is [NetVideoHunter](http://netvideohunter.com/).